# How do I return position 0 in an array if it exceeds the maximum position?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I return the value of position 0?
Let's say I have this code:

```
JButton[] arr = new JButton[3];
arr[0] = new JButton("Hello");
arr[1] = new JButton("Goodbye");
arr[2] = new JButton("Goodday");
```

How would I get the JButton "Hello" by calling 'arr[2+1]', for example?
Is it even possible?
Integers start over if you exceed 2'147'483'647, so I thought it would be possible with arrays too.

Comment: java is not python, negative indices will give you exceptions here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with modulo operator:

```
int position = 3;
JButton button = arr[position % arr.length];
```

Comment: How do I use that with this if statement? if (buttons[x + 1][y].getIcon() != b.getIcon())

Comment: `(buttons[(x + 1) % buttons.length]`

Comment: That worked, but now it's giving me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException since I'm also doing (buttons[(x - 1) % buttons.length], and it goes through every JButton in the array, starting at 0.

Comment: ((x - 1) % buttons.length) < 0 ? 0 : (x - 1) % buttons.length;